# Find sample name and directory name from a path

Tags: regex, perl

My script receives a complete path name of a file from another script and I am trying to break this full path name in perl and pass this information to my script.

I am unable to extract it using split, can anyone please suggest on how to approach this - 
I need to split a path which cold look like  - `path =` `/usr/local/projects/Tool/Work/Section12/Tool.Sample.2.pdf`

to extract these values  `Sample1` and `/usr/local/projects/Tool/Work/`, so that I can use these to assign values to two variables in my script for example `$Sample_id = Sample` and `$Dir=/usr/local/projects/Tool/Work/`

Can anyone please suggest?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't understand your requirement. You don't want the full path to the directory that the file is in, and you don't want the full file name. What are the rules for the things you want?

Comment: What are the rules to select `Sample01`?

Comment: My script passes my full path which looks like /usr/local/projects/Tool/Work/Part12/Tool.Sample01.2.pdf and here "Sample01" is the sample id which I need to extract and pass to another variable in the script. I made edits to the sample path above, I hope its more clear now

Comment: `File::Spec`. Regex based solutions have certain risks

Comment: I think you're a little lost. Your path is `/usr/local/projects/Tool/Work/Section12/Tool.Sample.2.pdf`, and you want to extract ` Sample1` from that, and then somehow assign `ABC` to `$Sample_id`. How can that happen?

Comment: Ahh sorry for that, my original question had "Sample" in the path( to which your answer is perfect) but I tried it to simplify the Sample name by writing "ABC", but while I was making changes you replied so I changed it back to original! Now the question is back to its original form. Thanks again!

Comment: @AnkP: *(I'm writing this with reference to the first iteration of your question, as it is the last self-consistent one.)* Discarding `Section12` from the path is such an odd requirement. It would help if you reassured us in the question that that is truly what you want to do. Selecting the correct part from the file name is also in question. What is it about `Sample01` in `Tool.Sample01.2.pdf` that defines it as the part of the string that you want to extract?

Comment: @AnkP: Thank you for that. It's *always* best to show as much as possible of your ***real data***. You will always make mistakes if you try to invent parallels that you *think* will behave the same, and you will have to come back and say, *well my* ***real*** *data isn't quite like that*! I hope you have your solution?

Comment: Thanks Borodin, the parent script creates multiple files like `/usr/local/projects/Tool/Work/Section12/Tool.Sample.2.pdf, /usr/local/projects/Tool/Work/Section13/Tool.Sample.3.pdf, /usr/local/projects/Tool/Work/Section14/Tool.Sample.4.pdf` and I need to just find the invariable sample name and the path before the creation of subsections .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the core [`File::Spec::Functions`](https://metacpan.org/pod/File::Spec::Functions) module so that your code respects any eccentricities of the platform you're working on. `splitdir` and `catdir` from that module separate and recombine path components, making your task mostly simple

I've used `splitdir` here to put the steps of your `$path` into array `@path`. The last element is the file name, which I've copied out using `pop`, and the second-from-last is `Part12`, which you don't seem to be interested in, so I've used another `pop` to get rid of that

Then all that's left is to rebuild `$dir_path` from what's left of `@path`, and extract the part of the file name that you're interested in

To do the latter there are several options, depending on what you mean. It could be the second field of the file name split on dots `.`, or the third from the end, split the same way. I've gone for the field that starts with `sample` in either upper or lower-case. A regex finds that for me

```perl
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

use File::Spec::Functions qw/ splitdir catdir /;

my $path = 'E:/usr/local/projects/Tool/Work/Part12/Tool.Sample01.2.pdf';

my @path = splitdir $path;

my $file = pop @path;        # Copy and remove the file name from the end
my $local_dir = pop @path;   # Remove `Part12` per requirement

my $dir_path = catdir @path; # Rebuild what is left of the path


# Pick the first subsequence of the file name that starts with `sample`
#
my ($sample) = grep /^sample/i, split /\./, $file;

print "\$sample = $sample\n";
print "\$dir_path = $dir_path\n";
```

#### output

```
$sample = Sample01
$dir_path = /usr/local/projects/Tool/Work
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two parts to this -- split the full path, and extract particular components of some of its parts. Splitting a file name with the full path into its components is nicely done by a few modules. Here I'll use the core module [`File::Basename`](http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Basename.html). Then the  path and filename can be processed for specific requirements, and here I'll use regex.

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use File::Basename qw(fileparse);

my $fullname = '/usr/local/projects/Tool/Work/Section12/Tool.Sample.2.pdf';

# Parse it into the path and filename
my ($filename, $path) = fileparse($fullname);

# Extract needed part of the path: all except last directory
my ($dirs) = $path =~ m|(.*)/.*/|;  # / stop editor coloring

# Extract needed part of filename: between the first `.` and the next
 my ($tag) = $filename =~ /[^.]+\.([^.]+)/;

print "$dirs\n$tag\n";
```

This prints

```
/usr/local/projects/Tool/Work
Sample
```

The regex for pulling parts out of the path and filename are both specific to the task. The first one uses the fact that we only need to drop *the* last component of the path, so the greediness of `.*` works out right. In the second one, I use the fact that the pattern goes between the very first `.` and the next.

---

Note that in the basic invocation above the extension is not extracted and the filename is returned with its extension. Thanks to [Borodin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/622310/borodin) for bringing this up in a comment. See the documentation, as should always be done with any suggested modules.

This is by far the most common need when working with full paths. But if you want to get the extension split off as well then pass another argument, which can be a list of extensions to seek or a regex. Then the file-name part will be returned without the extension.

```
my ($base, $path, $ext) = fileparse($fullname, @suffix_list);
```

For example, `@suffix_list` can be `qr/\.[^.]*/` and in this case we have

```
my ($base, $path, $ext) = fileparse($fullname, qr/\.[^.]*/);
print "$path\n$base\n$ext\n";
```

printing

```
/usr/local/projects/Tool/Work/Section12/
Tool.Sample.2
.pdf
```

A note on reliability, from docs:

> You are guaranteed that `$directories . $filename . $suffix` will denote the same location as the original `$path`.

Comment: [File::Spec](https://metacpan.org/pod/File::Spec) would make this much clearer, more portable, and less prone to mistakes. It makes a little more sense to use regex patterns on Linux file paths than on XML or HTML, but not by a big margin. If you're not considering portability then I would just start with `my @path = $path =~ m|[^/]+|g` and then manipulate the array

Comment: @Borodin  I use `File::Spec` and I like it. But `File::Basename` is just as solid and used and I think it is good to have an example of that as well. (I think that overall I use it more than the other one.) As for splitting into directories, I'd still go with the module from your solution. I use that in my own code for similar (and a few other) purposes.

Comment: @zdim: It's just that the results of `fileparse` don't really get you very far. `$suffix` will always be the empty string, so all it has done is separate the last element of the string as the file name. You need to do that again anyway to remove the parent directory, and you've had to resort to regex patterns to do most of the heavy work

Comment: @Borodin  I disagree with that. Splitting into path + filename is the most common need in parsing full paths.  It needs one extra step here, but other approaches do just as well.  With `File::Spec` you have to manipulate arrays and still need to process the filename itself.  Can't escape that.  Are you saying that this module is unsuitable for general use and that one should only use `File::Spec`?